# Getting data in JSON format from an API using express and nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, api, express, matomo

I am trying to get the analytics data from an API using expressjs. The data is in JSON format. The point is that I want to display the result in the view. I am able to get the data in the console, but I am not able to do that in the view.

Here is what I have tried so far:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');
http.get('http://localhost:8383/analytics/piwik/index.php?module=API&method=Actions.getPageUrls&idSite=1&date=yesterday&period=day&format=json&filter_limit=10', function(res){
  var body = "";
  res.on('data', function(chunk){
      body += chunk;
  });
  res.on('end', function(){
    var resp = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(resp);
  });
  app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Example app listening to port 3000");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options to do that:
1-you can use a tempting language for rendering the data in your app like handlebars or mustache of ejs and so many other chooses.
2- you can make an endpoint and make your client connects to it using ajax and then render the data using javascript (frameworks can help here)

Comment: Can you please be more elaborative? Absolute noob here. If possible, please point me to some code samples.

Comment: if you can't figure it out please reach out to me

Comment: Yeah, I can't figure it out.

Comment: just a minute i will make an example for you and give a url for it

Comment: This is a simple example for using handlebars

Answer (score 0):

After getting response you will have to render the data see example below:-

```
 var resp = {
        'name':'demoUsername',
        'contact': '+91-9876543210'
    }
    res.render('index', { resp: resp });
```

I am using EJS template engine see the code below:-

```
<html>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Contact</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><%= resp.name%></td>
      <td><%= resp.contact%></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```